# .play JavaScript not playing sound sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have made and alarm page using `.play()` method. But sometimes audio does not play and sometimes it plays. My code it gets executed but the MP3 audio does not get played.

What could be the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function () {
        if (alrm4 != alrm4a) {
          alrm4 = alrm4a;
          audio.play();
          blinker = 4;
        }
      }, 1000);
    });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var audio = new Audio('Sound.mp3');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing more context would be helpful. Your code refers to two variables (`alrm4` and `alrm4a`) that are not defined in the sample code you provided.

Chances are there was a problem loading the mp3 file or your condition, `alrm4 != alrm4a`, is not evaluating to true. Please edit your question to include the code which defines and manipulates these variables.

Comment: they are actually defined i didnt mention whole code here.. but it works even code gets executed. sound plays fine on firefox but in chrome sound plays for a while but after 5 minutes sounds stops playing even though the code gets executed successfully.